# WebGL not drawing lines

Tags: javascript, graphics, webgl

I want to draw a line in WebGL context but it isn't working. I can clear the canvas color so I know the program is compiled, but not sure where is the error.

The main part of the code is

```
  let canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");

  let gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);
  if (!gl) {
    alert("WebGL isn't available");
  }
  let program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader");
  gl.useProgram(program);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  let color = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "color");
  let colorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([1,0,0,1, 1,0,0,1]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(color, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(color);

  let vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
  let positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([1,1,1,1, -1,-1,-1,1]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);

  gl.drawArrays(gl.LINES, 0, 1);
```

The full code can be found [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/f6RCi9Mbr1WKuLC0iyrj/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your `drawArrays` call:

> count
>   Specifies the number of **indices** to be rendered.

Every line needs two indices: starting point and end point:

```
gl.drawArrays(gl.LINES, 0, 2);
```

[image: webgl line]